# outlook vba add recipient to outgoing emails

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need to add a specific email address to the CC field of every new email draft. The address needs to show up in the CC field so it can be removed if needed. How can I do this in VBA? Existing code prompts to add person if they are not already CC'ed, which is an unnecessary extra click on every email.

Please help, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Trap the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event, retrieve the current item using `Inspector.CurrentItem`, call `MailItem.Recipients.Add`.

```
Public WithEvents oInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set oInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Public Sub oInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
  Dim msg As Object
  Set msg = Inspector.CurrentItem
  If (msg.Class = 43) And (Not msg.Sent) Then
    Dim recip
    Set recip = msg.Recipients.Add("user@company.com")
    recip.Type = olCC
    recip.Resolve
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but this is beyond my outlook understanding. Is there a simple VBA script I can add to ThisOutlookSession? My original script was written by someone else..

Comment: My boss said don't distribute that. Not sure why, but I like my job haha. Is this still a simple script that can be created? I'm about to dive into a tutorial on writing VBA to get this done (may bit overkill).

Comment: Well, it is certainly easier for people here to tell you how to change your existing code rather than writing it all for you from the scratch.

Comment: If you know a simple way to CC a specific address automatically, that's awesome. I'm open to learning more VBA at this point, suggestions there are appreciated as well.